# LSTM to Predict Movie-Id based on tags and genres alone?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm

I want to predict/classify a movie based on the tags and genres.

Input being:

Genre

```
adventure animation children comedy fantasy
```

tag

```
pixar fun
```

output:

```
0  (MovieId)
```

I have 9742 movies. I have merged tags and genres into a single column. After which I tokenized them.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(MAX_NB_WORDS, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=X.shape[1]))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(9742, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

After training I have same output for all samples. Exact same array.

Comment: Why do you want to have sequential processing of the data?

Comment: Im still a beginner.. which processing would be better for this problem?

Comment: Simple neural networks should do.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa Tried that too! Still facing the same issue. All outputs are the same.

Comment: The given data is not sufficient to judge the reason for your output. How are you predicting?